# Can I use an Html helper to render hyperlink with images?

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper, hyperlink

Something like this

```
<a id="a1" runat="server" href="~/">
    <img id="logo" runat="server" src="/_assets/images/logo.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should remove the runat server from your sample...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could easily build your own helper, something like :

```
public static MvcHtmlString ImgLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string href, string src)
{
    TagBuilder a = new TagBuilder("a");
    a.MergeAttribute("name", name);
    a.GenerateId(name);
    a.MergeAttribute("href", href");

    TagBuilder img = new TagBuilder("img");
    img.MergeAttribute("src", src);

    a.SetInnerHtml(img.ToString(TagRendreMode.SelfClosing));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(a.ToString());
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Html.ImgLink("logo", "~/", "/_assets/images/logo.png");
```

this is not tested, feel free to customize it the way your want/need...